# Popup for different products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, ui-form

I have to make a pop-up window under the products on the sales page. Instead of redirecting to ordering, a feedback form should appear. The problem is that I do not know how to tie a pop-up window separately to each product in order to transfer its values ​​to the form. Js defines only the first press of the button, because the id of all buttons is the same.

```
<?php foreach ($block->getSaleCategory(16) as $product) : ?>

<div><?php echo $block->getMediaPath($product->getEntityId()) . $product->getImage() ?></div>
<div><?php echo $product->getName() ?></div>
<button type="button" id="openModel" class="custom_model_popup" >Order</button>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<div style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div id="myModel">
        <form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'sale/frontend/sendmail' ?>" method="post" id="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
            <input name="email" value="email">Email<br>
            <input name="name" value="name">Name<br>
            //there must be hidden fields with product data
        </form>

    </div>
    <span id='ajax_loader1' style='display:none'>
            <img src="<?php $this->getBaseUrl() ?>pub/media/home/loader-2.gif" style="height: 150px;width: 150px">
    </span>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function($,modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                title: 'Product Question',
                closeText: 'Close',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Submit'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function (data) {
                        var form_data = jQuery("#form-validate").serialize();
                        jQuery('#ajax_loader1').show();
                        //alert(form_data);
                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url: "<?php  echo $block->getBaseUrl() . 'sale/frontend/sendmail' ?>",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data : form_data,
                            success: function(data){
                                jQuery('#ajax_loader1').hide();
                                console.log(data);
                            },
                            error: function(result){
                                console.log('no response !');
                            }
                        });
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }],
                /**
                 * Escape key press handler,
                 * close modal window
                 */
                escapeKey: function () {
                    if (this.options.isOpen && this.modal.find(document.activeElement).length ||
                        this.options.isOpen && this.modal[0] === document.activeElement) {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }
            };
            var popup = modal(options, $('#myModel'));
            $("#openModel").on("click",function(){
                $('#myModel').modal('openModal');
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

How can I implement a pop-up window for each product and transfer its values ​​to the form?